# .htaccess: Transfer name to index.php if not directory public

Tags: .htaccess

I have this piece of code:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule> 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I don't know how to allow only directory with name "public" which is inside folder where is .htaccess, other names than this dir should be transfered to index.php. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `RewriteCond` to exclude *public* directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Now, the redirection would only work for `/public` directories only. If you want the `url` to just have the rest of the path that's below public like `url=subfolder/page.php` for `/public/subfolder/page.php` use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^public/?(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: If you mean the browser URL doesn't change to reflect that you got redirected; change the flags to `[R=301,L]`. Currently, its redirecting but silently i.e. without letting the browser know.

Comment: It's working, but in reverse side. I would like to enable only public and disable all other folders. Now is disabled public and others allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule (?!^public(/.*|)$)^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,NC,R=302]

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```